# jQuery image slider first loading amalgimation of 3rd and 4th images instead of 1st

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, slider, banner

I'm trying to make a basic image slider based on the code found [here](http://www.htmldrive.net/items/show/6/Automatic-Image-Slider-with-CSS-jQueryred.html), but edited for a longer banner. Problem is now whenever it loads instead of showing the 1stimage it shows a amalgamation of the 3rd and 4th image, [first image of slider](https://i.stack.imgur.com/in6nE.png). Once you move it to the second image it works fine even when you then go back to the first there is nothing wrong.

The jQuery code is too long to post here but it is unedited from the download above (I'm not familiar with it and didn't know how to edit it)

I did change the html file to the following though:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head>


    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

        <style type="text/css">
            body {
                background: #222;
                margin: 0; padding: 0;
                font: normal 10px Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
            }
            *{outline: none;}
            img {border: 0;}
            .container {
                width: 790px;
                padding: 0;
                margin: 0 auto;
            }
            .folio_block {
                position: absolute;
                left: 50%; top: 50%;
                margin: -140px 0 0 -395px;
            }


            /*--Main Container--*/
            .main_view {
                float: left;
                position: relative;
            }
            /*--Window/Masking Styles--*/
            .window {
                height:175px;   width: 900px;
                overflow: hidden; /*--Hides anything outside of the set width/height--*/
                position: relative;
            }
            .image_reel {
                position: absolute;
                top: 0; left: 0;
            }
            .image_reel img {float: left;}

            /*--Paging Styles--*/
            .paging {
                position: absolute;
                bottom: 0px; right: -7px;
                width: 178px; height:47px;
                z-index: 100; /*--Assures the paging stays on the top layer--*/
                text-align: center;
                line-height: 40px;
                background: url(paging_bg2.png) no-repeat;
                display: none; /*--Hidden by default, will be later shown with jQuery--*/
            }
            .paging a {
                padding: 4px;
                text-decoration: none;
                color: #fff;
            }
            .paging a.active {
                font-weight: bold;
                background: #474747;
                border: 1px solid #171717;
                -moz-border-radius: 3px;
                -khtml-border-radius: 3px;
                -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
            }
            .paging a:hover {font-weight: bold;}
        </style>

</head><body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function() {

            //Set Default State of each portfolio piece
            $(".paging").show();
            $(".paging a:first").addClass("active");

            //Get size of images, how many there are, then determine the size of the image reel.
            var imageWidth = $(".window").width();
            var imageSum = $(".image_reel img").size();
            var imageReelWidth = imageWidth * imageSum;

            //Adjust the image reel to its new size
            $(".image_reel").css({'width' : imageReelWidth});

            //Paging + Slider Function
            rotate = function(){
                var triggerID = $active.attr("rel") - 1; //Get number of times to slide
                var image_reelPosition = triggerID * imageWidth; //Determines the distance the image reel needs to slide

                $(".paging a").removeClass('active'); //Remove all active class
                $active.addClass('active'); //Add active class (the $active is declared in the rotateSwitch function)

                //Slider Animation
                $(".image_reel").animate({
                    left: -image_reelPosition
                }, 500 );

            };

            //Rotation + Timing Event
            rotateSwitch = function(){
                play = setInterval(function(){ //Set timer - this will repeat itself every 3 seconds
                    $active = $('.paging a.active').next();
                    if ( $active.length === 0) { //If paging reaches the end...
                        $active = $('.paging a:first'); //go back to first
                    }
                    rotate(); //Trigger the paging and slider function
                }, 7000); //Timer speed in milliseconds (3 seconds)
            };

            rotateSwitch(); //Run function on launch

            //On Hover
            $(".image_reel a").hover(function() {
                clearInterval(play); //Stop the rotation
            }, function() {
                rotateSwitch(); //Resume rotation
            });

            //On Click
            $(".paging a").click(function() {
                $active = $(this); //Activate the clicked paging
                //Reset Timer
                clearInterval(play); //Stop the rotation
                rotate(); //Trigger rotation immediately
                rotateSwitch(); // Resume rotation
                return false; //Prevent browser jump to link anchor
            });

        });
    </script>

    <div class="container">

        <div class="folio_block">

            <div class="main_view">
                <div class="window">
                    <div style="width: 3160px; left: -2370px;"
                         class="image_reel">
                        <a href="#"><img
                                src="reel_1.jpg"
                                alt=""/></a>
                        <a href="#"><img
                                src="reel_2.jpg"
                                alt=""/></a>
                        <a href="#"><img
                                src="reel_3.jpg"
                                alt=""/></a>
                        <a href="#"><img
                                src="reel_4.jpg"
                                alt=""/></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div style="display: block;" class="paging">
                    <a class="" href="#" rel="1">1</a>
                    <a class="" href="#" rel="2">2</a>
                    <a class="" href="#" rel="3">3</a>
                    <a class="" href="#" rel="4">4</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>



</body></html>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I'm a little out of my depth

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem appears to be in you HTML. The style declarations in the .image_reel div are what's causing your issue.

Comment: Thanks David, looks like it is something to do with the absolute position. Don't know if I have been staring at a screen too long or what but I'm not quite sure how to fix it (changing the position to fixed or anything breaks the rotation). Any tips? Sorry.

Comment: Changing this line: `<div style="width: 3160px; left: -2370px;" class="image_reel">` to this: `<div class="image_reel">` should solve your issue. The left positioning is what is making the first and second slide show up at the same time, and the width isn't even necessary.